# Load entities into TypeORM OrmConfig from Library project to Application Project

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have two projects in my application:

1. App/AppServer
2. libraries/domain

Below is the folder structure:

```
+---apps
|   \---AppServer
|       +---config
|       +---node_modules
|       +---src
|       |   +---auth
|       |   |   \---dto
|       |   +---config
|       |   +---masterDataHttp
|       |   \---tasks
|       |       +---dto
|       |       \---pipes
|       \---test
+---libraries
|   \---domain
|       +---node_modules
|       \---src
|           \---masterData
\---node_modules
```

I have some entities defined under libraries\domain\src\masterData and a few entities under apps\AppServer\src\tasks.

My ormconfig is defined under apps\AppServer\src\config. It imports the entities using

```
__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'
```

Using above we can import entities under apps\AppServer\src. But I am trying to figure out what best approach to import entities defined under libraries\domain\src.

One option is import entities directly using

```
import { Entity1, Entity2 } from '@myproj/domain'
```

What is the recommended practice/approach to address this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

- Importing the entities directly

```js
entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}', Entity1, Entity2]
```

Or you could wrap all of the entities of the library in a variable:

```js
// libraries/domain

export const entities = [Entity1, Entity2];

// importing the entities

import { entities } from '@myproj/domain' ;
...
entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}', ...entities]
```

- Importing the entities with path string as you already do

```js
entities: [
  __dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}',
  'src/libraries/domain/**/*.entity.{js,ts}'
]
```

This will just work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yash. It helps. The first two approaches work, however, I could not make  "importing entities using path" work.

Comment: hmm the path is not correct it means. it looks the packages are outside of your app context? in that case, the path is looking different from the above. it will be good to import the entites directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all entities automatically by add `autoLoadEntities: true` to `forRoot`.

After doing this, all entities that were registered by `forFeature` will be loaded. Also, be aware that relationships that are not explicitly registered won't be loaded.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities